# How do you pass data/parameters to another activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parameter-passing, bundle

How to pass data/parameter values from one activity to another in android?

I have used

```
loginname=txtloginname.getText().toString();
password=txtpassword.getText().toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("loginname", loginname);
bundle.putString("password", password);
Intent newIntent=new Intent();
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK,newIntent);
finish();
```

But I can only get loginname value  How to put both login and password key and value?

Comment: Can you post the code how you are receiving it to another activity

Comment: hi Stuti, I get like this :extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just say `newIntent.putExtra("name",value);` use it multiple times to add multiple data. And depending on the data you stored call `getStringExtra("name");` in the next activity.

Comment: hi devA,  it is getExtra() ? I don't find getExtraString().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method:

```
getStringExtra()
```