# Carrying double value throughout classes

Tags: java, android

I'll try to cut down on the information but this app is supposed to tally a score each time you press a radio button. There are 4 screens with radio buttons and then the fifth screen shows you what your score is.

The calculation always comes to the number 4 though. There is no addition at all no matter what is pressed. Where am I going wrong?

```
    RadioButton gpa1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA1);
    RadioButton gpa2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA2);
    RadioButton gpa3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA3);
    RadioButton gpa4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA4);       

    //Calculation based on GPA question
    if (gpa1.isChecked()){calculation = calculation + 1;}
    else{ if (gpa2.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 2; }
    else{ if (gpa3.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 3; }
    else{ if (gpa4.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 4; }
    else{calculation = 0.0; }}}}
```

This is the first main class and after they select their answer and press the next button it goes to a second page with another question and 4 more answers that are also supposed to be added to the calculation variable.

Here is some more of the coding to show what is fully covered:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    //RESTORES SAVED STATES
    if (savedInstanceState == null ){calculation = 0.0;}
    else{calculation = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CALCULATION);}

    addListenerOnButton();

    RadioButton gpa1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA1);
    RadioButton gpa2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA2);
    RadioButton gpa3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA3);
    RadioButton gpa4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA4);       

    //Calculation based on GPA question
    if (gpa1.isChecked()){calculation = calculation + 1;}
    else{ if (gpa2.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 2; }
    else{ if (gpa3.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 3; }
    else{ if (gpa4.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 4; }
    else{calculation = 0.0; }}}}

    //Get button to do button stuff like go to the next page
    Button butGPA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butGPA);
    butGPA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Main2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    }
```

Comment: Where is your `if` statement? Is it in `onCreate()`?

Comment: It is. I tried to lessen the amount of info I put on here because my last question didn't get much attention

Comment: That's your problem. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `if` statement is in `onCreate()`, the value is always going to be the `RadioButton` which is checked by default which apparently is the first one and is why you always get 4 for the value. Move

```
 if (gpa1.isChecked()){calculation = calculation + 1;}
else{ if (gpa2.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 2; }
else{ if (gpa3.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 3; }
else{ if (gpa4.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 4; }
else{calculation = 0.0; }}}}
```

to some event such as the `Button` `onClick()` or whatever you use to move to the next `Activity`. You could also set the value in an `onCheckedChangeListener()`.

Remember `onCreate()` is *only* going to be called the first time an `Activity` starts after it has been destroyed. So, any code you put in there (unless in some event listener) isn't going to change from within `onCreate()`.

**Edit**

```
butGPA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
         if (gpa1.isChecked()){calculation = calculation + 1;}
         else{ if (gpa2.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 2; }
         else{ if (gpa3.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 3; }
         else{ if (gpa4.isChecked()) {calculation = calculation + 4; }
         else{calculation = 0.0; }}}}
        Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Main2.class);
        i.putExtra("calc", calculation);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Pass the value to each `Activity` like that then to get the value (in or after `onCreate()`) do something like

```
Intent i = getIntent();
double calc = i.getDoubleExtra("calc", 0.0);
```

That is assuming the variable is originally a `double` though I'm not sure why it isn't an `int`. You would want to check for `null` and things but that should get you started anyway.

Comment: Ok I found a tutorial showing to have it listened by using "addListenerOnButton()", will that work?

Comment: Sure but you can just use `onCheckedChange()` and set the value there. Or, as I said, put this code inside of the `onClick()` or whatever you already use to go to the next `Activity`.

Comment: Could you help explain but showing me some code example? Also, I really appreciate your help. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I'm assuming you are stating to use a public void onClick()?

Comment: Sure, can you show me how you go to the next activity? Is it inside of an onClick?

Comment: How are you getting the value of `calculation` to each `Activity`?

Comment: That edit with the new code is beautiful! I'm not sure how to get the value of the calculation to each activity. I was trying to tackle one problem at a time. Right now I have each activity set up with the same code except it says Main.calculation = Main.calculation + # instead.

Comment: When I posted your code into the onClick snippet, it won't recognize the radiobutton's anymore. Should I also move that portion into the same area of code? I mean... the RadioButton gpa1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GPA1); portion

Comment: I have added a little about getting the value. Yes, either move them there or declare them as member variables and initialize them in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Great! I added the Intent to capture the calculation amount but the .getDoubleExtra is underlined in red and not being recognized. I placed in the onCreate (mainly because I don't have much else going on in that class) and it's after all the button information you've helped me with. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I made a couple changes. You can hover over those issues that are underlined in red and see what the problem is to do a little self-debugging. You will need to learn how to do some of that.

Comment: Ok, great! You were awesome! I wish there were a way to give you more points because you deserve it. I didn't know what to put as an extra beside the "calc", in the getDouble. You've been a godsend! =D

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for points. I forgot the default value in case the method returns `null` in `getDoubleExtr()`. Make sure you go through the docs for all of this because it explains it in there. Good luck

Comment: I know you're not looking for points but just wanted to point out that you're a good person. Thanks! I got the assignment done and it works like a charm now. =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 newIntent.putExtra("varname",value);
```

to set the attribute value. and can get the value at new intent

```
getStringExtra("varname");
```

and pls refer this question: [How do you pass data/parameters to another activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340423/how-do-you-pass-data-parameters-to-another-activity-in-android). it may help.