# Pass strings to another Activity in Android

Tags: android, string

Maybe someone can help me. I would like to pass two strings from to an other activity. This is the code where i generate the strings:

```
private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null;
        String name = null;

        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        // column index of the contact name
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        // Set the value to the textviews
        textView1.setText(name);
        textView2.setText(phoneNo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would like to pass phoneNo and Name to my MainActivity

I tried to do a SharedPreference and load DefaultSharedPreference in my MainAcitivity without any Result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass data/parameters to another activity in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340423/how-do-you-pass-data-parameters-to-another-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("key", keyId);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it as from second activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value;
if (extras != null) {
 value = extras.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: What i do is: i go from MainActivity to ContactActivity(thats where the strings are) where i select a contact. When i do startActivity(intent) in my ContactActivity than the programm opens the MainActivity again.

Answer (score 0):

in current activity add this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PHONE", phoneNo);
intent.putExtra("NAME", Name);
startActivity(intent);
```

in main activity add this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String phonNo = intent.getStringExtra("PHONE");
String Name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
```

Comment: What i do is: i go from MainActivity to ContactActivity(thats where the strings are) where i select a contact. When i do startActivity(intent) in my ContactActivity than the programm opens the MainActivity again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent

// to pass data from one activity to other via Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("phone", phoneNo);
intent.putExtra("name", name);
startActivity(intent);
```

//To receive data in other activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String phonNo = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: What i do is: i go from MainActivity to ContactActivity(thats where the strings are) where i select a contact. When i do startActivity(intent) in my ContactActivity than the programm opens the MainActivity again.

Comment: what is problem then?

Comment: it shouldnt open the MainActivity? I just want to save the phoneNo and name somewhere so i can read them in my MainAcitivity and not swap activity when i load the contact within my ContactActivity??

Comment: what exactly you want to do? you want to store data somewhere but not redirect to MainActivity?, and when you visit MainActivity next time data should be available to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your comments that you want to pass the strings once you're closing your ContactActivity without opening again the MainActivity (not adding it to the stack).

You can start an Activity and wait for a result, so in your Main Activity change

```
   startActivity(intent);
```

for

```
   startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then, in your ContactActivity you can set your result as the following:

```
   intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("PHONE", phoneNo);
   intent.putExtra("NAME", Name);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

And in onActivityResult you can implement onActivityResult to retrieve the data

```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
       if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){

            if(resultcode == RESULT_OK){
                 String phoneNo = data.getStringExtra("PHONE");
                 String name = data.getStringExtra("NAME");
                 //do whatever you want
            }else{
                 //do something else
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: so in ContactActivity i do: 
'Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("PHONE", phoneNo);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);'
and in MainActivity i call onActivityResult?

Comment: In ContactActivity you use the intent as I post. setting the MainActivity.class is not required. The setResult will return the intent with the extras to the MainActivity once ContactActivity is dismissed. And you don't have to call onActivityResult, just implement it. It will be called when it receives a result